# adjust segmented controller so that it can be scrolled horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I adjust segmented controller so that it can be scrolled horizontally in order to display the whole text inside the segmented cell?

I am using 5 segments, and the text inside each segment's cell is long.

Comment: What do you mean by segmented controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Include your whole view inside a scrollview. This will enable you to scroll horizontally.